# How to display Salesforce Validation Rule error messages at once via the API

Tags: salesforce

In the current version of Salesforce,

- IF I have multiple Validation Rules Error message defined on one object
- AND IF these rules are not respected when clicking on Save
- THEN I get multiple error messages (all at once).

This is what I would like to have when using API calls.

As it is now, I am only getting error messages one by one via API calls. Is there any way to display all error messages at once, as it is in the Salesforce interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently API processing stops at the first error and report thats, there's no way to have to report all the errors.